# Mat.Depth() Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, opticalflow

I'm working on LK Optical Flow method using Opencv. when i tried to execute my code I'm receiving the following error.

> Assertion failed (ncorners >= 0 && corners.depth() == CV_32F) in cornerSubPix, file /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20140819-1745/modules/imgproc/src/cornersubpix.cpp, line 257
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-opencv2-2.4.9-2precise-20140819-1745/modules/imgproc/src/cornersubpix.cpp:257: error: (-215) ncorners >= 0 && corners.depth() == CV_32F in function cornerSubPix

here is part of my code

```
vector<Point2f> cornersA; 
cornersA.reserve(maxCorners); 
vector<Point2f> cornersB; 
cornersB.reserve(maxCorners);


goodFeaturesToTrack( imgA,cornersA,maxCorners,qualityLevel,minDistance,cv::Mat(),blockSize,0,k);


cornerSubPix( imgA, cornersA, Size( win_size, win_size ), Size( -1, -1 ), 
              TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, 0.03 ) );


// Call Lucas Kanade algorithm
```

I checked in internet about the error I’m receiving. Its mostly because of define Point2d instead of Point2f. I couldn't find anything more than that. I'm new to this area. It will be really grateful if you guys could help me solve this problem. Thanks..

Comment: Looks like using Point2f is only half part of the assertion. You have to make sure ncorners is >=0 as well. I assume ncorners refers to `cornersA` and this is empty (no features found?). Check `cornersA.size()` before calling `cornerSubPix`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error with the Android/Java version of OpenCV.  I even dumped the value of ncorners to check it out and it seemed OK.

It finally went away when I stoped running goodFeaturesToTrack and cornerSubPix on the OLD image, and ran them on the NEW image.

So maybe try

```
goodFeaturesToTrack( imgB,cornersA,maxCorners,qualityLevel,minDistance,cv::Mat(),blockSize,0,k);


cornerSubPix( imgB, cornersA, Size( win_size, win_size ), Size( -1, -1 ), 
          TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 20, 0.03 ) );
```

or whatever you call your newer image.  If anyone can figure why this happens, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same error. Look at `cornerSubPix()` source code:

```
void cv::cornerSubPix( InputArray _image, InputOutputArray _corners,
                   Size winSize, Size zeroZone,
                   TermCriteria criteria )
{
    Mat corners = _corners.getMat();
    int ncorners = corners.checkVector(2);
    CV_Assert( ncorners >= 0 && corners.depth() == CV_32F );
    Mat image = _image.getMat();
          ...
}
```

So, it's only two possible reasons.

1. `_corners` is not of appropriate type.
2. `_corners.checkVector(2)` return negative -> check if you have empty `_corners` array (that was my case).